# how to show and hide forms by selecting option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

---

I want to display two forms.
First Form should display on click of first option and
second form should display on click of second option
Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.
here's my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" data-role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for="What">What do you want?:</label>
    <select class="selectpicker col-md-4" id="What" title="Select Any Option">
        <option id="opt1">Sell Embroidery Machine</option>
        <option id="opt2">Buy Embroidery Machine</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

here are the forms:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal hide" id="form1" data-role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for=
            "Name">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name"
               required="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for=
            "surname">Sur Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder=
                "Sur Name" required="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "Contact">Contact Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="Contact" placeholder=
                "Contact Number" required="" type="tel">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for=
            "Email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder=
                "Email Address" required="" type="email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "Location">Where Are you located?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="location" placeholder=
                "Location" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "radio1">This is a qoute for:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="radio1">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios" type="radio"> My Self</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios" type="radio"> My Business</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios" type="radio"> On Behalf of someone else</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios" type="radio"> On Behalf of another business</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for=
            "BusinessName">Business Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="BusinessName" placeholder=
                "Business Name" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "checkbox">I would like an embroidery machine because:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Embroidery
                machine is my hobby</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> I would like to start my
                business</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> I would like upgrade my
                emroidery machine</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> To Extand my business to
                include embroidery</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "EmbExp">Embroidery Experience:</label>
    <select class=
                    "selectpicker col-md-4" id="EmbExp" title="Select Any Option">
        <option>
            Beginner Embroider (0-6 month)
        </option>
        <option>
            Intermediate Embroider (1-2 years
        </option>
        <option>
            Advanced Embroider (2+ years)
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "IntIn">I am Intersested in:</label>
    <select class=
                    "selectpicker col-md-4" id="IntIn" title="Select Any Option">
        <option value="Home embroidery machine (R2 000-R20 000)">
            Home embroidery machine (R2 000-R20 000)
        </option>
        <option value=
                        "Combo sewing/embroidery machine (R20 000-R100 000)">
            Combo sewing/embroidery machine (R20 000-R100 000)
        </option>
        <option value=
                        "Semi-Industrial embroidery machine (R90 00-R160 000)">
            Semi-Industrial embroidery machine (R90 00-R160 000)
        </option>
        <option value=
                        "Industrial embroidery machine (R70 000-R150 000)">
            Industrial embroidery machine (R70 000-R150 000)
        </option>
        <option value=
                        "Industrial embroidery machine (R150 000-R400 000)">
            Industrial embroidery machine (R150 000-R400 000)
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "radio2">New or Pre-owned? :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="radio2">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios1" type="radio"> New Embroidery Machine</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios1" type="radio"> Used
                Embroidery Machine</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios1" type="radio"> Quote
                For Both New And Used Embroidery Machine</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios1" type="radio"> On
                Behalf of another business</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "IHav">I am Intersested in:</label>
    <select class=
                    "selectpicker col-md-4" id="IHav" title="Select Any Option">
        <option value="R2 000 - R5 000">
            R2 000 - R5 000
        </option>
        <option value="R5 000 - R10 000">
            R5 000 - R10 000
        </option>
        <option value="R10 000 - R50 000">
            R10 000 - R50 000
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="R50 000 - R100 000">
            R50 000 - R100 000
        </option>
        <option value="R100 000 - R200 000">
            R100 000 - R200 000
        </option>
        <option value="R200 000 - R400 000">
            R200 000 - R400 000
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "radio3">I require financing:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="radio3">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios2"
                          type="radio"> Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios2" type="radio"> No, I
                already have financing arranged</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios2" type="radio"> No, I
                will be paying cash</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "Radio4">Do you already have a digitizing software
        :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="radio4">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios3"
                          onfocus="enableField();" type="radio"> Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input name="optionsRadios3" onfocus=
                    "disableField();" type="radio"> No</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group hide fade" id="NameOfSoft1">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for=
            "NameOfSoft">Name Of Digitizing Software:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="NameOfSoft" placeholder=
                "Name" required="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for="txtArea">Any Additional Comments:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtArea" placeholder="Additional Comments" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-default col-sm-offset-5" href="">Submit
    Quote</a>
</form>

<br>

<form class="form-horizontal hide" id="form2" role="form"></form>
```

and the script:

```
$(function (){

console.log('jquery loaded...');
//$('#What').change(function(){
 //   console.log($("#What option").filter(":selected"));
//});

$('#form #what #opt1').click(function(){
    console.log("Option 2 Clicked");

    if($("#form1").hasClass('hide'))
    {
        console.log("First Statement Passed...");
        if($("#form2").hasClass('in'))
        {

        console.log("Nested Statement 1 Passed...");
            $('#form2').removeClass('in');
            $('#form2').addClass('hide');
            $('#form1').removeClass('hide');
            $('#form1').addClass('in');
        }
        else
        {
        console.log("Nested Statement 2 Passed...");
            $('#form1').removeClass('hide');
            $('#form1').addClass('in');
            $('#form2').removeClass('in');
            $('#form2').addClass('hide');

        }           
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Second Statement Passed...");
        if($("#form1").hasClass('in'))
        {
            console.log("Nested Second Statement Passed...");
            $('#form1').removeClass('in');
            $('#form1').addClass('hide');
            $('#form2').removeClass('hide');
            $('#form2').addClass('in');
        }
    }

});

$('#form #opt1').click(function (){
    console.log("Option 1 Clicked");
    //ZI70u7nfZGzr1vB5fR2N6w
    if($("#form1").hasClass('hide'))
    {
        console.log("First Statement Passed...");
        if($("#form2").hasClass('in'))
        {

        console.log("Nested Statement 1 Passed...");
            $('#form2').removeClass('in');
            $('#form2').addClass('hide');
            $('#form1').removeClass('hide');
            $('#form1').addClass('in');
        }
        else
        {
        console.log("Nested Statement 2 Passed...");
            $('#form1').removeClass('hide');
            $('#form1').addClass('in');
            $('#form2').removeClass('in');
            $('#form2').addClass('hide');

        }           
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Second Statement Passed...");
        if($("#form1").hasClass('in'))
        {
            console.log("Nested Second Statement Passed...");
            $('#form1').removeClass('in');
            $('#form1').addClass('hide');
            $('#form2').removeClass('hide');
            $('#form2').addClass('in');
        }
    }

});
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bjkv7gh/4/)

Comment: $(#form1).hide(); $(#form2).show() and $(#form1).show(); $(#form2).hide()

Comment: add your css .... what code does your classes [in,hide] have this is a simple task in jquery showing a form on click option ... show your css

Comment: i can't see two `form` and `select` element in fiddle example

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any css i am using bootstrap 3

Comment: @HumayunAhmed did my code work for you? and my code can work with bootstrap too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if this is what you want ..... Easier way to do it instead of adding classes and checking classes

HTML

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-1" for="What">What do you want?:</label>
    <select class="selectpicker col-md-4" ititle="Select Any Option" id="myselect">
        <option id="op1">Sell Embroidery Machine</option>
        <option id="op2">Buy Embroidery Machine</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
<form id="formop1" class="myform">
    <span>Hi i am form1</span>
</form>

<form id="formop2" class="myform">
    <span>Hi i am form2</span>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.myform{
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselect').change(function(){
    var id=$('#myselect option:selected').attr('id');

    var formid="#form"+id;

    $('.myform').hide();
    $(formid).show();


});
    });
```

What i have done here is given your subforms a common class *myform*;`class="myform"` and set its CSS property to `display:none` then using JS i have used change function to select option and obtained the ID of the options under the select. As you can see the id of the option is `id="op1"` and the id of the form related to that option is `id="formop1"` . So basically what i am trying to do here is just concatenate the ids and show the respective forms .... Here is a fiddle with alerts for your reference ... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nephilim11/rtbq5vcy/)

NOTE: THIS WORKS FOR n NUMBER OF OPTIONS & FORMS

Answer (score 0):

Try these. I dont see ur css or 2 forms on fiddle, so giving a short answer    :

```
$( "#What" ).change(function() {

        var selectedId=$('#What option:selected').attr('id');

             if(selectedId == 'opt1')
            {
                $("#form2").hide();
                $("#form1").show();
                // You can add all ur css stuff here
            }
        else{
            $("#form1").hide();
             $("#form2").show();
            // add ur csss stuff here
        }

    });
```